# click not getting recognized in java swing

Tags: java, swing, events, click

I am not sure why but my clicks on both the save and load menuItems are getting recognized, I am not sure why. The code have been auto generated and my logic in that method looks fine to me?

I did the same thing on the login button yet it is working perfectly fine. What could be the problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Avoid adding your code as picturem, instead add it as text

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3bwC4B5k ,, You can use this link to see the code ..

Comment: Please add the code to the question, not a link to a paste bin account.

Comment: The code for your [mre] should be posted in this forum.

Comment: sorry, it is the very minimum that I can share. I have no idea where the error is coming  from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my clicks on both the save and load menuItems are getting recognized

I assume you means to say are "not" getting recognized.

Don't use a MouseListener.

Instead you should be using an `ActionListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for working examples.

Comment: oh, i will get familiarized.. 

I thought that it was fine because my IDE allowed me to do it..